# Помогите с правильной записью в файл

Tags: python, файлы

```
F1=open('test4.txt','r')
F2=open('test55.txt','w')
for i in range(10):
    X=F1.readline()
    X=X.split(' ')
    del X[5]
    X1=[]
    for j in range(5):
        Y=int(X[j])
        X1.append(Y)

        X2 = str(sum(X1))
    F2.write(X2)
    print(X2)
F1.close()
F2.close()
```

В файл записывается все в одну строку, а нужно каждую сумму записывать на новую линию

Comment: ну добавляй после каждой строки еще "\n"

Comment: просто добавьте переход строки после каждой суммы - и все